# Getting Unique 1:1 results with many to many is possible

Tags: sql

Ok hope that title wasn't misleading

I have (among other columns) the following info

```
PO_NUMBER                    PO_TRACKING_NO
-------------------------------------------
321A                            C100
321A                            C100
321A                            C102
321B                            C100
321B                            C012
321C                            C012
```

I need to write code so that `PO_NUMBER` and `PO_TRACKING_NO` match up ONCE, any other results are eliminated...but the `PO_TRACKING_NO` can still reference other `PO_NUMBER` and `PO_NUMBER` can reference other `PO_TRACKING_NO`...so with the above table, I would want the below results

```
PO_NUMBER                  PO_TRACKING_NO
-----------------------------------------    
321A                          C100
321A                          C102
321B                          C100
321B                          C012
321C                          C012
```

all must be done via queries, I am grabbing this info from views, I am not allowed to edit/change the tables/views (though in this case I don't think that would have been a problem)

EDIT: sorry text not coming out in a neat form, trying to format it :( [ I'm pretty new here]

Comment: if you wan't your code to look clear, just highlight the code and click the `{ }` from the editor control.

Comment: I'm using oracle, but the SQL cannot include and Oracle SQL, because the query will be going into a 3rd party program that reads SQL Server only....so i can't store variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the are only two columns in your table, `DISTINCT` is here to help you,

```
SELECT DISTINCT PO_NUMBER, PO_TRACKING_NO
FROM tableName
```

Comment: indeed, that was what i tried first, however if i do that than the PO_NUMBER that has two different tracking numbers, one of them is eliminated

Comment: i take back what i said, for whatever reason, yea it absolutely worked

but how do i add more columns to this query that are NOT part of the distinct, whenever i try something i get an error

Answer (score 1):

A `DISTINCT` should work, but a `GROUP BY` will just give you a bit more info:

```
SELECT 
 [PO_NUMBER], 
 [PO_TRACKING_NO],
 COUNT(*) AS [Occurrences]
FROM [VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE]
GROUP BY 
 [PO_NUMBER], 
 [PO_TRACKING_NO]
ORDER BY
 [PO_NUMBER], 
 [PO_TRACKING_NO]
```

Comment: thanks! absolutely worked, would give you +up but my rep isn't high enough :(

Comment: It's not about earning rep, it's about solving problems. Though, you should be allowed to mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: @user1955517: now your rep is high enough :-)

Comment: Here's my next question (follow up rather)...whenever i use these group by functions and everything, if i try and grab more columns, it gives me a "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: If you add columns to the SELECT-statement, you should add them to the GROUP BY-clause too.

Answer (score -1):

Just use DISTINCT like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PO_NUMBER, PO_TRACKING_NO
FROM YourTable
```